# Объект класса Objective-c

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c

Привет! Пытаюсь программировать для `iOS`. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Создал класс `User`. В нем методы `getOrder` и `setOrder`.

В `ViewController` создаю объект класса `User`:

```
User *myUser = [[User alloc] init];
```

Далее получаю данные с `text field` и записываю `[myUser setOrderTo:toOrder];`
И перехожу на другой `ViewController`.

Вопрос: как теперь получить записанные данные. Как мне вызвать ранее созданный `*myUser`?

Comment: Передавайте созданного юзера в следующий контроллер)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое что нужно знать - `set` и  `get` методы в `objective-c` генерируются автоматически, достаточно написать

```
@interface User : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString order;
@end
```

Для передачи параметра просто создаешь `property User` в другом `ViewController` и присваиваешь ему значение перед переключение контроллера, выглядит это примерно так

```
NextViewController *nextViewController = [[nextViewController alloc] init];
nextViewController.myUser = self.myUser;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!:)
NSString удалось передать.
У меня еще вопрос: как правильно создать и использовать класс в котором хранятся данные(get и set)?
Неужели каждый раз создавать объект класса: User *myUser = [[User alloc] init]; ?
Могу ли я напрямую обратиться к классу User и сразу в него записывать и считывать?

Comment: Можно сразу использовать `myUser` если в классе `NextViewController`, которому принадлежит `myUser`, прописать 

`-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.myUser = [[User alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую к классу невозможно обратиться. Если Вам необходимо обмениваться данными между разными ViewController'ами, то следует использовать Singleton. Очень удобная вещь. Это класс, который может создать только один объект и к нему можете обращаться с чего угодно, храня в нем необходимые значения.